# Magento - redirect user group after login

Tags: magento

How can I redirect different user groups to different pages in Magento ?

what I want to do is to assign a category to each customer group to redirect the user to it on login.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please provide more details, this is an order of magnitude harder if lots of groups and lots of pages than retail/wholesale distinction with trade group going to customised dashboard.

Comment: Thanks, 
what I want to do is to assign a category to each customer group to redirect the user to it on login

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this for an approach:

Consider starting with an existing module such as:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/MagePsycho/extension/3763/custom_login_redirect

Then adding your own logic. For the group name of a customer you can try this:

```
$groupId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId();

$group = Mage::getModel ('customer/group')->load($groupId)->getCode();
```

If you then have your categories named as per your groups you can do a redirect to http:// + base_url + $group therfore removing the need to explicitly work out what category page to load.

Comment: Thanks Mathew, I like your proposition ! :)

and If my categories have not the same names as groups ? 
What can I do in these case ?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Cheat again ;-) You can add in URL rewrites to handle that, in admin menu catalog -> URL rewrite management and add a few custom ones in. Depends on scale of what you are trying to achieve, you don't want to be hard coding a new UI for it and custom URL rewrite is webmaster-maintainable.

Answer (score 2):

I have not tried this. I think you need to do the following on the `customer_login` event:

```
$session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
$category = // A category object based on $session->getCustomerGroupId()
$session->setBeforeAuthUrl($category->getUrl());
```

Comment: Thanks clockworkgeek,

how can I get the category object based on $session->getCustomerGroupId()  ??

Comment: That depends on which category you want for each customer group. Only you know that.

Answer (score 2):

Go to /app/code/local/MagentoPycho/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php and replace this:

```
$session->setBeforeAuthUrl(Mage::helper('customer')->getAccountUrl());
```

with this:

```
$groupId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId();
if($groupId == 5) {
    $session->setBeforeAuthUrl('http://google.com');
} else {            
    // Set default URL to redirect customer to
    $session->setBeforeAuthUrl(Mage::helper('customer')->getAccountUrl());
}
```

Be sure to put your Group ID instead of the "5" and your redirect URL instead of google.com.

*I just tried it.*

Answer (score 0):

In order to redirect the customer as per customer group, there is a commercial extension:
http://www.magepsycho.com/custom-login-redirect-pro.html
really worths trying. FYI many merchants are using this module for their magento sites.

Happy e-commerce!!
Regards