# Magento: custom login redirect for specific customer group

Tags: javascript, php, magento

I have a custom login that should redirect a specific customer group to a specific page.
I am using the following code for the form, but I don't know where I should do the check for the group id:

```
<?php
 $login_url  = 'http://specific-url/';
 $http_mode  = (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS']==='on');
 if($http_mode)
  $login_url  = str_replace('http:', 'https:', $login_url);  
 ?>
  <form method="post" id="login-form" action="<?php echo $login_url ?>">
 <div class='full'>
            <label>
                <?php echo $this->__('Email Address') ?>
            </label>
            <sup>*</sup>
            <div class="data_area">
                <input type="text" name="login[username]" value="<?php echo $this-        
  >htmlEscape($this->getUsername()) ?>" id="email" class="input-text required-entry     
   validate-email" title="<?php echo $this->__('Email Address') ?>" />
            </div>
        </div>
    <div class='full'>
            <label>
                <?php echo $this->__('Password') ?>
            </label>
            <sup>*</sup>
            <div class="input-box">
                <input type="password" name="login[password]" class="input-text 
       required-entry validate-password" id="pass" title="<?php echo $this-  
      >__('Password') ?>" />
            </div>
        </div>

     <button type="submit" class="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Login') ?>"    
     name="send" id="send2"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Login') ?></span></span> 
     </button>

     <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    var loginForm = new VarienForm('login-form', true);
     //]]>
     </script>
```

Comment: I found the answer in another thread:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6436345/magento-redirect-user-group-after-login

Answer (score 0):

MY suggestion is, when you submit the form, the email id and password will be validated using the database and after successful validation, the user will be redirected to the User Home Page. So before redirecting to the home page check for the user group of the user and send a custom redirect to another page.

I hope it will work.